why is my EDK2 build not offering a PXE boot option?
I am building OVMF.fd from the repo. Specifically, I am downloading tianocore/edk2, and running build on x86_64. I then try to boot qemu from it, and despite the correct qemu options, it does not attempt a PXE boot.
My command-line:
qemu-system-x86_64 -display none -m 4096 -smp 4  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,readonly,file=OVMF_CODE.fd -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=OVMF_VARS.fd -serial mon:stdio -global ICH9-LPC.noreboot=false -watchdog-action reset -rtc base=utc,clock=rt -netdev user,id=eth0,net=192.168.1.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.1.10,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22,tftp=/var/netboot/,bootfile=ipxe.efi -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=eth0,romfile="" -netdev user,id=eth1,net=192.168.2.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.2.10 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=eth1,romfile="" -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci -qmp unix:/var/tmp/qmp.sock,server,wait=off -machine q35 -cpu SandyBridge -smbios type=1,serial=31415926

Interestingly, if I use OVMF.fd from the system package (apt install ovmf, i.e. /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd), it works fine.
My build is fairly simple:
git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2.git /edk2
cd /edk2
git checkout ba0e0e4c6a174b71b18ccd6e47319cc45878893c
. edksetup.sh
build -b DEBUG -t GCC5 0x X64 -p OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc -v -DNETWORK_TLS_ENABLE -DNETWORK_HTTP_BOOT_ENABLE -DNETWORK_IP4_ENABLE -DSECURE_BOOT_ENABLE=TRUE -DTPM2_CONFIG_ENABLE=TRUE -DTPM2_ENABLE=TRUE -DFD_SIZE_4MB

I have a report that if I enable kvm acceleration on qemu it works, although my particular testbed cannot do that.
Of course, I tried -b DEBUG and -b RELEASE.
I did check the output (10000 lines), I see Building ... for /edk2/NetworkPkg/UefiPxeBcDxe/UefiPxeBcDxe.inf and /edk2/NetworkPkg/DnsDxe/DnsDxe.inf and /edk2/NetworkPkg/Ip4Dxe/Ip4Dxe.inf and /edk2/NetworkPkg/HttpBootDxe/HttpBootDxe.inf and /edk2/NetworkPkg/Udp4Dxe/Udp4Dxe.inf etc.
That does not necessarily mean it is included, but I do not know how to check that.
FWIW, I also built with -DDEBUG_ON_SERIAL_PORT and have about 2200 lines of boot time debug logs.
What am I missing/doing wrong?
ANSWER: I figured it out. The build of 2024-05 changed PXE so that it depends on an rng device. See this issue. So either your device must have an actual RNG, or (for qemu, as in my case), you need to boot it with -device virtio-rng-pci.
